# Park accessible by public transport in Eastern Canada in October

Tags: public-transport, canada, hiking, national-parks

I'll likely travel to Canada this autumn and I would like to go on a multi-day hike. I have however no car.

Is there any park (national, provincial, ...) in Eastern Canada (Ontario, Quebec, New Brunswick, Nova Scotia or Prince Edward Island) that offers long hikes (at least 2 days) and that is accessible by public transport during the first half of October?

Many parks seem to have a summer shuttle but it usually stops at the end of August.

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Algonquin Parkbus](http://www.parkbus.ca/schedules-toronto.php) runs until at least October 13th - after that it switches to an as-yet-unannounced winter schedule. However it stops going to and from Algonquin the last weekend of September. On the matter of hiking, they say:

> Highland Backpacking Trail (19 & 35 km loops) is easily accessible via our Lake of Two Rivers stop. Short 800m trail leads to Mew Lake office, where backcountry permits can be picked up. The Western Uplands Backpacking Trail (32, 56 and 88 km loops) can be accessed via West Gate stop, where permits are available (trailhead is 2km down the road)

If you're not familiar with your options around hiking in Algonquin, check [the Friends site](http://www.algonquinpark.on.ca/visit/camping/backpacking-in-algonquin-park.php). You can certainly go for two days if not longer.

In October the bus goes to Killarney, which also has lovely hiking trails:

> Killarney Provincial Park offer some great day hikes that are easily accessible directly from the George Lake Campgrounds. The campground also serves as the trailhead to the famous multi-day La Cloche Silhouette Trail (78km loop, 7-10 days), only recommended for experienced backpackers.

Grundy Lake has only day trails and French River doesn't have hiking. So this solution will carry you through September (but plan carefully to make sure you can get back home on this bus since it doesn't run every day) but not into October.

Comment: In fact the only bus in october is not going to Algonguin but Killarney and French River only

Comment: I didn't even read the column headings because I thought the bus only served Algonquin. It's great news for me that it also serves Killarney though it's a bummer you can't use it for an October Algonquin hike.

Answer (score 5):

Greyhound runs to [Marathon, Ontario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon,_Ontario) at the gates of [Pukaskwa National Park](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/on/pukaskwa/index.aspx) (17 hours from Toronto, twice daily).  However, you still need to find a solution for the last 20 km or so.  It seems there [exists a local taxi service](http://www.yellowpages.ca/bus/Ontario/Marathon/Marathon-Taxi/1012317.html?what=Taxis&where=Marathon%2C+Ontario+ON).  The [coastal hiking trail](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/on/pukaskwa/activ/hiking-randonnees/b.aspx) is 60 km, which Parks Canada claims to take a full week to hike.

The [Can-Ar coach](http://www.can-arcoach.com/slider/schedule-services) connects Moore Falls, Ontario (3½ hours from Toronto).  From there, one can hike into the [Queen Elizabeth II Wildlands Provincial Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Elizabeth_II_Wildlands_Provincial_Park) on the [Ganaraska trail wilderness section](http://ganaraskawilderness.wikifoundry.com/).  As this is a "regular" bus, it runs often and you don't need to book it a long time before, as might be the case for the Parkbus to Algonquin or Killarney.

Comment: sounds good, just for Moore Lake, the arrival of the multi-day hike that is shown is a bit in the middle of nowhere, so most likely I would need a taxi as well.

Comment: @Vince Right, the other end is more tricky, so you might consider hiking back and forth.  Washago has buses from Ontario Northland and occasionally a VIA rail train at inconvenient times.

Answer (score 3):

The [Fjord-du-Saguenay national park](http://www.sepaq.com/pq/sag/index.dot?language_id=1) in Quebec, near Tadoussac, has a couple long hikes and in particular a hike starting from the bay Ste Marguerite to Tadoussac.

It is possible to access Tadoussac by bus with the company Intercar (from Montreal).

This is then possible to access the Ste Marguerite bay thanks to [a private shuttle](http://www.ferme5etoiles.com/fr/fr/activites/randonn%C3%A9e-p%C3%A9destre) (by the so-called 5 star farm, and its cost is 74$) apparently run year-round but it should probably be booked ahead.

This is eventually possible to start a four-day hike with shelters along the way and as the hike ends in Tadoussac (on the road 138), there is no risk to be stuck on a deserted road at the end of the hike.