# How to access Killarney Provincial park (Ontario) by public transportation

Tags: public-transport, national-parks, ontario

There is near Sudbury, Ontario a provincial park called [Killarney Provincial park](http://www.ontarioparks.com/park/killarney). According to [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/28968/3044) there is a bus that runs, sometimes, to access it. However this bus seems to only run a few weekends in August.

I looked at Greyhound website and while they have stops called Killarney, ON and Killarney Rd, ON, there does not seem to be any bus serving them.

Is there a public transportation service that serves Killarney provincial park during the summer (ideally not only in August)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Killarney Provincial Park](https://www.ontarioparks.com/park/killarney) website it is served by the [Park Bus](https://www.parkbus.ca/). In 2019 the Park Bus [from Toronto to Killarney Provincial Park](https://www.parkbus.ca/killarney) has trips scheduled for August and one for the Canadian Thanksgiving weekend in October. According to the page linked above they aren't planning on adding additional dates. In 2015 they had a [similar schedule](https://web.archive.org/web/20150912093135/https://www.parkbus.ca/schedules-toronto).

FYI Park Bus services other parks closer to Toronto with much greater frequency.

Looking on other travelling sites yields the same result: the only other public transport alternative to reach the park is by taxi. Taking Killarney, ON as your starting point, [Rome2Rio seems to agree with this.](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Killarney-ON-Canada/Killarney-Provincial-Park) This is true unless you are *that* daunting and willing to hike as suggested in [this answer on another Q&A website](http://forum.virtualtourist.com/Killarney_Provincial_Park-907730-11-3375216/Public-transport-to-Killarney.html):

> Probably the only way would be to take an Ontario Northlands, or Greyhound bus to the intersection with Highway 637, about 30 kilometres south of Sudbury and hike (or hitchhike) the 67 kilometres to the park.

Comment: I think I would have hiked if the bus dropped me in Killarney ("only" 10km)

Comment: The post about the Park Bus was initially made in 2015. It's 2019 and they've substantially expanded the number of parks that they service and the frequency of their service :) :) :).